# Horizontal ListView not measuring itself properly when wrapped inside a MvxListView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

Whoever answers this gets a **cookie**.

My aim is to have a 2 dimensional ListView.

A `ListView` containing a number of `HorizontalListView`s (courtesy of Cheesebaron & co.)

Problem is:

`HorizontalListView` does not resolve its own `Height` when `match_parent/wrap_content` is used. Though the `Width` is.

When explicitly giving a `Height` each `HorizontalListView` shows fine.

I have tried to resolve the `Height` myself inside `HorizontalListView.OnMeasure` which receives `HeightMeasureSpec` of zero/Unpecified but I failed.

I have made the project public on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/diehard10/twodim)

Please help. Sorry if my writing is confusing.

Thanks.

(Remember the cookie)

Comment: I had hoped the nice note in the GitHub repository would scare you away from using the horrible HorizontalListView implementation I made more than 3 years ago. I think the problem lies with the HorizontalListView since it does not implement OnMeasure and probably does not tell Android how to measure itself.

Comment: ok thanks. I saw but thought I would try anyhow. Do you have any other layout recommendation for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: http://androidconceptspp.blogspot.com/2015/02/create-horizontal-listview-using.html This seems like a nice and simple approach